# Is there any way to export PowerPoint slides to PNG while having each image the name of the slide?

Tags: office-365, google-slides, microsoft-office

I need to have a presentation with PowerPoint in several languages, so after the translation, I do not know the content of the images anymore.

Then, if I do export the file to PNG, the images have numbers. Since I do not understand the content of the slides anymore, I need a way where I could keep the name of the slide (written in English). In such a way, I will be able to the content of the slide with just the name of the slide, not the content of the slide.

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se] Why was [tag:google-slides] included in this question? Please show what you tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: I do not care if the solution works with PowerPoint or any other presentation software.